# Espresso test for bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, bottom-sheet

I am creating an espresso test for bottom sheet where the sheet has 5 linearly arranged textview and the first textview is visible and clicking the first textview will expand the entire bottom sheet revealing all the items, and then the third item is needed to be clicked for the test to pass.

The problem is that espresso doesn't click the textview of the bottom sheet after expanding until I put a `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

I even tried IdlingResource, I set it to false once the click is registered on the first item and after the onStateChanged is called on bottomSheetBehaviour I set it to true again but still no help.

This doesn't work :

```
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem1)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem3)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem3)).perform(click());
```

This does :

```
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem1)).perform(click());
Thread.sleep(1000);
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem3)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.toolsItem3)).perform(click());
```

Comment: Do you have device animations disabled in dev settings?

Comment: The animation are turned off but still the bottom sheet slowly animates upwards @Be_Negetive

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem? I am having the same issue :/

Comment: Have you tried `SystemClock.sleep(1000);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. From my point of view the Thread.sleep() solution sadly seems like the way to go.

But I used a third party library called https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility to wait until the state of the bottomsheet changes rather than a fixed period. I used it like this:

```
await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(() -> fragment.bottomSheetBehavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Where fragment is the fragment to test which you can get for example like this:

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) activityTestRule.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag");
```